# head and grep simultaneously

Tags: bash, unix, grep, unix-head

Is there a unix one liner to do this?

```
head -n 3 test.txt > out_dir/test.head.txt
grep hello test.txt > out_dir/test.tmp.txt
cat out_dir/test.head.txt out_dir/test.tmp.txt > out_dir/test.hello.txt
rm out_dir/test.head.txt out_dir/test.tmp.txt
```

I.e., I want to get the header and some grep lines from a given file, simultaneously.

Comment: With your command sequence, if one of the first three lines contains `hello`, it is duplicated. I guess that's a bug?  Otherwise, the proposed solutions are not equivalent in that regard.

Comment: @user2719058 good catch, you are right the first 3 lines do not contain the grep character.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use awk:

```
awk 'NR<=3 || /hello/' test.txt > out_dir/test.hello.txt
```

Comment: Whenever you find yourself doing multiple head to grep to sed to grep to tail to cut type of stuff, you should always think `awk`. Awk isn't that hard to learn for basic file manipulation, and can handle multiple tasks with aplomb.

Comment: @DavidW.: Very good point, awk can replace all those multiple pipeed command in a single command most of time.

Answer (score 8):

You can say:

```
{ head -n 3 test.txt ; grep hello test.txt ; } > out_dir/test.hello.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `sed`

```
sed -n '1,3p; /hello/p' test.txt > out_dir/test.hello.txt
```

Comment: What if `hello` appears in the first three lines? You'll double up that header line.

Comment: @DavidW. Aha! good point. I see you've already provided solution to it. devnull's solution will also go for a toss in such scenario

Answer (score 3):

The [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19936655/368630) solution is the best, but I'll add a sed solution for completeness:

```
$ sed -n test.txt -e '1,3p' -e '4,$s/hello/hello/p' test.txt > $output_file
```

The `-n` says not to print out a line unless specified. The `-e` are the commands `'1,3p` prints ou the first three lines `4,$s/hello/hello/p` looks for all lines that contain the word `hello`, and substitutes `hello` back in. The `p` on the end prints out all lines the substitution operated upon.

There should be a way of using `4,$g/HELLO/p`, but I couldn't get it to work. It's been a long time since I really messed with sed.

Comment: You are using a non portable `sed` option and removing lines from the original file which is not what is asked for.

Comment: @jlliagre The `-i` is a standard *Unix* mapping, but hasn't made it into GNU utilities that are found on Linux. I am surprised by this because GNU usually leads in options. The `-e` is on both GNU and Unix platforms as well as `-n`. You can remove the `-i` and pipe it to another file which will remove the _incompatible issue_. The `awk` solution is better, but this was for completeness. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: `sed` portable options are only `-n`, `-e` and `-f`. `-i` is a Gnuism, not sure why you wrote the opposite.

Comment: It's also in BSD versions of `sed`. This includes OS X. The man.cx which is suppose to be the GNU version of the manpage didn't show the `-i` option. However, linux.man.de do. I don't have access to Solaris, and the _newest_ version of the SunOS/Solaris webpage is from 1998. I've removed `-i` from my answer anyway.

Comment: (Legacy) BSD `sed`didn't have `-i`. This option was first introduced in 2001-09-25 by Paolo Bonzini in the GNU sed source code. It was later adopted by other implementations but is still not in latest Solaris according to its manual web page, from 2013: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/sed-1.html#scrolltoc.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, I would go `awk` but here is an `ed` solution for the pre-`vi` nostalgics:

```
ed test.txt <<%
4,$ v/hello/d
w test.hello.txt
%
```

Comment: Please mention somewhere in your post that `ed` is the standard editor. `;)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf No need to mention it, everybody knows that's the only one `;)`